# Html.DropdownList(allsundaysinmonth) set default to sunday just past

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have no idea how to work this out but my drop down list code looks as follows:

in the action:

```
  DateTime[] allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now);
  DateTime[] allSundaysInLastMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)); 
  List<SelectListItem> listOfSundays = new List<SelectListItem>();
  foreach (DateTime dt in allSundaysInThisMonth)
  {
    listOfSundays.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
      Text = dt.Name,
      Value = dt.Id.ToString(),
      Selected = dt.CompanyId == Id
    });

    return listOfSundays;
  }
```

I need to take the last two sundays af last month and all sundays of this month, but not future sundays, and build a list with all these sundays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something i did while on a past project

```
public List<SelectListItem> CompanySelectList(List<Company> companyList, int selectedId = 0)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listToReturn = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Company c in companyList)
        {
            listToReturn.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = c.CompanyName,
                Value = c.CompanyId.ToString(),
                Selected = c.CompanyId == selectedId
            });
        }
        return listToReturn;
    }
```

just modify your T so it will return what you need.

Comment: <p style="color:Red"><%: Html.DropDownList("date", ((DateTime[])ViewData["Sundays"]).Select(day => new SelectListItem() { Text = day.ToString(), Value = day.ToString(), Selected = day.ToString() == DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()}))%>
</p>  Is not quite working? Have I got it wrong? thanks

Comment: what i did was just a core example. You can make your own IEnumerable<SelectListItem> in wich you can use my example.

Comment: edited my answer with something more solid. This is just one way you can achieve returning a collection of selectlist items for your dropdownlist, there are also other methods.

Comment: I dont quite understand though. I dont want to re-write  code. Thought it would be easier

Comment: It's programming, its not meant to always be easier.

Comment: I see now, I am trying out your idea, but not sure if I got it right so far? Please see top for new code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the current date and start looping down, if the date then returned is a sunday set this value to be selected.